# How to create a classic asp page for using the asp.net mvc core 6 component/widget?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp-classic

I had developed an application in Asp.Net MVC Core 6 (.Net 6).
Now I need to use the classic asp page to call my asp.net mvc core 6 components/widget.

If I use simple .html page then everything is working as expected but when I rename the page with extension .asp then browser throw this error.

Please see below

[image]

If you want to see my files hierarchy then please look into the below picture

[image: 264608-image.png]

and this is the actual rental.asp page source.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang=en>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>test.</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>  
    
     <div id="wrapper">
             <!-- Main Content -->
             <div class="maincontentwrapper" style="overflow:auto;">
                 <div class="maincontenthome">
                     <div class="page-information">
                         <br /><br />
                               <div id="CarWidget">
                                   <script>
                                       function loadCarWidget() {                                          
                                           var getcurrentPagePath = window.location.href;
                                           if (getcurrentPagePath) {
                                               $.ajax(
                                                   {
                                                       url: "https://localhost:7177/paramvehicle?path=" + getcurrentPagePath, type: "GET", dataType: 'text'
                                                       , success: function (result) {
                                                           //debugger;
                                                           $("#CarWidget").html(result);
                                                       },
                                                       error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                                                           var msg = '';
                                                           if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                                               msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                                                           } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                                               msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                                                           } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                                               msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                                                           } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                                               msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                                                           } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                                               msg = 'Time out error.';
                                                           } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                                               msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                                                           } else {
                                                               msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                                                           }
                                                           $('#CarWidget').html(msg);
                                                       },
                                                   });
                                           }
                                       };
                                       loadCarWidget();
                                   </script>
                               </div>                        
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What are the steps which are required to use classic asp pages in this way ?
Please correct me and guide me.

Comment: How you're running the app? If it is using the Kestrel webserver, I don't think it supports ASP files. You may need to rewrite the asp file to controllers or run the asp files in IIS and call the URLs from your asp.net core app

Comment: I am just hitting the F5 or click on Play button from visual studio 2022.  I think by default Asp.Net Mvc Core 6 is using the Kestrel web server.  I have a directory under wwwroot in my source code and in that directory, I have .html file and .asp files. .Html files are working perfectly but .asp files are not.

Comment: Yes, HTML will work because it can be executed by the client. But for ASP files you need a web server.

Comment: Why use `.asp` anyway when the code looks like static HTML with an AJAX request?

Comment: Actually My client was using my Widget Application developed in Asp.net MVC Core 6. And My client application was developed in classic asp. Thats' why I want to create a single solution but it can't be possible then It is Fine now.  I created a two  paths now. One with .html file for my local testing and development and the other is for my client .asp .

Comment: Classic ASP won't run on any server other than IIS, and it's disabled by default.  If IIS isn't configured to serve pages with a .asp extension it will behave as if they don't exist and give you a 404 not found error.  This page might help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/370931/does-iis-in-windows-10-support-an-asp-web-site.html